# Add/Remove Input Fields Dynamically Odoo

Tags: odoo

I want to add and remove input fields dynamically in the form but I have no ideia whether it's possible or how to do it. Can someone help me with this problem?

I'd like to create something like this:

[check the image, please!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDTiM.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid what you want to do isn't possible in Odoo to the best of my knowledge.

The reason is that the fields in the view are mapped directly to fields in the model which in turn are mapped to the database.

I'm pretty sure with some hacking around you can use something like JQuery to modify the DOM and arbitrarily insert input fields into the DOM but those input elements would be as good as useless because there would be no way to get their value or work with them because they wouldn't be tied to Odoo in any way.

I suspect that you're dealing with an [X Y](http://xyproblem.info/) problem.

You can actually do this, but that's when you're building a website with Odoo not a module.

The closest you can get with a module is to remove and add fields using `xpath`. but when you're adding fields, those fields must exist in your model definition before they can be of any use to you.

Comment: Thanks, @danidee. I was thinking the same but I needed a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.
first solution : since all the views defined in 'ir.ui.view' so you can write on the columns of a specific view, you can create a new one.

second solution : there are a method called fields_view_get that will return to you a the view related to that object, so you call the super method and make your changes and return the object as you see in the exemple below from 'crm.lead'

```
 def fields_view_get(self, cr, user, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    if view_type == 'form' and context and context.get('opportunity_id'):
        # TODO: replace by get_formview_action call
        lead_type = self.browse(cr, user, context['opportunity_id'], context=context).type
        view_lead_xml_id = 'crm_case_form_view_oppor' if lead_type == 'opportunity' else 'crm_case_form_view_leads'
        _, view_id = self.pool['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference(cr, user, 'crm', view_lead_xml_id)
    res = super(crm_lead,self).fields_view_get(cr, user, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        res['arch'] = self.fields_view_get_address(cr, user, res['arch'], context=context)
    return res
```